# How to change a column from NULL to NOT NULL in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

For example, there is a table named Table1.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    aa INT PRIMARY KEY,
    bb INT
);
```

I wanna change bb to not null.But sqlite dont support ALTER MODIFY.
So what i is :

```
CREATE TABLE sqlitestudio_temp_table AS SELECT *
                                          FROM Table1;

DROP TABLE Table1;

CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    aa INT PRIMARY KEY,
    bb INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (
                       aa,
                       bb
                   )
                   SELECT aa,
                          bb
                     FROM sqlitestudio_temp_table;

DROP TABLE sqlitestudio_temp_table;
```

And there will be an error:

```
Could not commit table structure. Error message: NOT NULL constraint failed: Table1.bb
```

Comment: If you add the parameter "not null" to a column that contains null values an error will occur. you need `SELECT aa, ISNULL(bb, 0 ) FROM sqlitestudio_temp_table` to replace the nulls with zero or you could ignore them with `SELECT aa, bb FROM sqlitestudio_temp_table WHERE bb IS NOT NULL` to ignore null bb's.

Comment: Thx, it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to make a column NOT NULL.

In this case, it does not work because the column already contains NULL values.
So you have to either remove those rows:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE bb IS NULL;
```

or replace the NULL values with any other value:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET bb = ... WHERE bb IS NULL;
```